# Matrices A+B=AB implies A commutes with B

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $A+B=AB$. I have an interesting proof that this implies $A$ commutes with $B$, but the proof only works when $||B|| \lt 1$. I'm looking for a way to salvage the proof so that it works for all $B$.

$$A=AB-B$$
$$A=(A-I)B$$
by repeatedly substituting $A$ with $(A-I)B$ on the RHS, $$A= (A-I)B^N - \sum_{i=1} ^{N-1} B^i$$

Since the space of $n\times n$ matrices is Banach (hence complete) under the standard operator norm, the limit $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}B^i$ is well defined given $||B|| \lt 1$. Hence, taking the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$, $$A =  -\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}B^i$$

Now the LHS commutes with B, hence so does the RHS.

**Is there some trick to extend the method to work with any $B$ where $||B|| \geq 1$?** I know that the result is true due to another simple algebraic proof, but I'd like to see if this method can be salvaged.

Comment: $A$ will alays be equal to $-B(I-B)^{-1}$. So your question looks basically like a question about how to expand $(I-B)^{-1}$ in full generality, but everybody knows that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k}z^k$ is $1$ ...

Comment: But maybe there is some way to perturb the problem into the instance where B is small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$   (A-I)(B-I) = AB - A - B + I = I  $$
so
$$  (B-I)(A-I) = I  $$
and $BA = AB = A+B$

Comment: Thanks Will, this was the algebraic proof I mentioned. But I'm looking for a way to salvage my method.

Comment: Uh be careful Will this crucially uses the rank-nullity theorem...

Comment: @Freeze_S, $A-I$ and $B-I$ have full rank and are invertible

Comment: The conclusion fails in the infinite dimensional case: $(A-I)(B-I)=I\nRightarrow (B-I)(A-I)=I$ or shortly $CD=I\nRightarrow DC=I$ ...take for example left and right shift operator that are both everywhere defined, then $LR=I$ but $RL\neq I$.

Comment: @Freeze_S, good to know. I had wondered just a bit about infinite dimension.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S I think you have given evidence that my method cannot be generalized since it works in the infinite dimensional case. At least not if I don't use the finite dimensionality somewhere.

Comment: What thought process led you to this proof? I mean, how would one come up with it?

Comment: @JKEG if $A,B$ were real numbers and $I$ meant $1,$ this would be taking the quadratic polynomial ab - a - b and making a quadratic form. Rather than diagonalizing, into some $c x^2 - d y^2$ as a form of the relevant hyperbola, going instead to the purely translated hyperbola $(a-1)(b-1).$

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps not quite what you’re looking for, but here is another algebraic method : I claim that $I-B$ must be invertible.

Otherwise, the kernel is nontrivial, and we have a nonzero $x$ such that $Bx=x$. But then $A+B=AB$ yields $Ax+Bx=ABx$, so $Bx=0$ which is absurd.

So $I-B$ is invertible. Let $\chi_B$ be the characteristic polynomial of $B$. We have just shown that $1$ is not a root of $\chi_B$, so $\chi_B$ is coprime to $X-1$. We then have a Bezout identity $Q(X)(X-1)+P(X)\chi_B(X)=1$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we deduce $Q(B)(B-I)=I$ so $(I-B)^{-1}=-Q(B)$. Then $A=-BQ(B)$ commutes with $B$.

The moral of the story : $(I-B)^{-1}$ (and therefore $A$) is always a polynomial in $B$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use of Cayley Hamilton and what Q is?

Comment: @Mark please see my updated version.

Comment: The P should be a Q in P(B)(I-B) = I. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a flaw as there are cases for $B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $I-B$ invertible but $I-B=\sum_{k=0}^\infty B^k$. The entries never repeat and can't be a polynomial.

Comment: @Freeze_S There is no flaw. In general the polynomial (which I call $Q$) will have nothing to do with a Taylor expansion.