# Brezis' exercise 6.18.1: does $S_r$ or $S_{\ell}$ belong to $\mathcal{K}(E)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E := \ell^2$ with its norm $|\cdot|_2$. An element $x\in E$ is denoted by $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots)$. Consider the operators
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> S_r x &= (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, \ldots), \\
> S_{\ell} x &= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_{n+1}, \ldots),
> \end{align*}
> $$
> respectively called the *right shift* and *left shift*.
>
> 1. Determine $\|S_r\|$ and $\|S_{\ell}\|$. Does $S_r$ or $S_{\ell}$ belong to $\mathcal{K}(E)$ ?

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

1. 

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
|S_r x|_2 &= \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2} = |x|_2, \\
|S_{\ell} x|_2 &= \sqrt{\sum_{n=2}^\infty |x_n|^2} \le |x|_2.
\end{align*}
$$

Then $\|S_{\ell} \| \le \|S_r\| =1$. If we pick $x=(0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0, \ldots)$. Then $|x|_2= |S_{\ell} x|_2 =1$. Then $\|S_{\ell} \|=1$. We have $S_r$ is an isometry, so it is an isometric isomorphism. Then $S_r$ is certainly not compact.

We define $x^n = (x^n_m)_{m\ge 1} \in E$ by $x^n_m= 1$ if $n=m$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $|x^n|_2=1$ for all $n$. Also, $|x^n-x^m|_2 = \sqrt{2}$ for all $1 \le m <n$. Then $(x^n)$ does not have any convergent subsequence in $E$. On the other hand, $S_\ell x^{n+1} = x^n$ for all $n\ge 1$. Hence $( S_\ell x^n)_n$ does not have any convergent subsequence in $E$. So $S_\ell$ is not compact.