# Brezis' exercise 6.18.5: prove that $\sigma(S_{\ell})=[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E := \ell^2$ with its norm $|\cdot|_2$. An element $x\in E$ is denoted by $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots)$. Consider the operators
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> S_r x &= (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, \ldots), \\
> S_{\ell} x &= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_{n+1}, \ldots),
> \end{align*}
> $$
> respectively called the *right shift* and *left shift*.
>
> 1. Determine $\|S_r\|$ and $\|S_{\ell}\|$. Does $S_r$ or $S_{\ell}$ belong to $\mathcal{K}(E)$?
> 2. Prove that $EV(S_r) = \emptyset$.
> 3. Prove that $\sigma\left(S_r\right)=[-1,1]$.
> 4. Prove that $E V (S_{\ell}) = (-1, 1)$. Determine the corresponding eigenspaces.
> 5. Prove that $\sigma(S_{\ell})=[-1,1]$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (4, 5). Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

4. 

Clearly, $S_\ell$ is not injective and thus $0 \in EV(E_\ell)$. Let $\lambda$ be a non-zero real number. For $x \in E$,
$$
(S_\ell - \lambda I)x = (x_{n+1} - \lambda x_n)_{n\ge 1}.
$$

Then $x \in N (S_\ell - \lambda I)$ iff $x_{n+1} = \lambda x_n$ for all $n\ge 1$ iff $x_{n+1} = \lambda^n x_1$ for $n \ge 1$. We have $|x|_2 < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2 = |x_1|^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\lambda|^n < \infty$ iff $x_1 =0$ or $|\lambda| < 1$. Then the existence of $x \in N (S_\ell - \lambda I) \setminus \{0\}$ is equivalent to $|\lambda| < 1$. Then $E V (S_{\ell}) = (-1, 1)$. Also,
$$
N (S_\ell - \lambda I) = \{ (\lambda^n h)_{n \ge 0} : h \in \mathbb R\}.
$$

5.

I already [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728432/brezis-exercise-6-18-1-does-s-r-or-s-ell-belong-to-mathcalke) in (1) that $\|S_\ell\|=1$. By *Proposition 6.7* (in the same book), $\sigma(S_\ell)$ is compact and $\sigma(S_\ell) \subset [-\|S_\ell\|, \|S_\ell\|]=[-1, 1]$. Let $\lambda \in \{\pm 1\}$. By (4), it remains to prove that $S_\ell - \lambda I$ is not surjective.  For $x \in E$,
$$
(S_\ell - \lambda I)x = (x_{n+1} - \lambda x_n)_{n\ge 1}.
$$

Let $x, y \in E$ such that $y=(1, 0, 0,\ldots, 0, \ldots)$ and $(S_\ell - \lambda I)x=y$. Then
$$
x_2= \lambda x_1 + 1, x_3= \lambda (\lambda x_1+1), x_4 = \lambda^2 (\lambda x_1+1), \ldots, x_{n+1} = \lambda^{n-1} (\lambda x_1+1), \ldots
$$

Then the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is not convergent. Hence $x \notin E$ and thus $y \notin R(S_\ell - \lambda I)$. This completes the proof.