# Let $x_{n+1} := \frac{x_n-y_{n+1}}{\lambda}$ for $n \ge 1$. Can we prove that $|x|_2 < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E := \ell^2$ with its norm $|\cdot|_2$. An element $x\in E$ is denoted by $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n,\ldots)$. Consider the operators
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> S_r x &= (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}, \ldots), \\
> S_{\ell} x &= (x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_{n+1}, \ldots),
> \end{align*}
> $$
> respectively called the *right shift* and *left shift*.
>
> 1. Determine $\|S_r\|$ and $\|S_{\ell}\|$. Does $S_r$ or $S_{\ell}$ belong to $\mathcal{K}(E)$?
> 2. Prove that $EV(S_r) = \emptyset$.
> 3. Prove that $\sigma\left(S_r\right)=[-1,1]$.
> 4. Prove that $E V (S_{\ell}) = (-1, 1)$. Determine the corresponding eigenspaces.
> 5. Prove that $\sigma(S_{\ell})=[-1,1]$.
> 6. Determine the adjoints $S_r^*$ or $S_{\ell}^*$.
> 7. Prove that for every $\lambda \in(-1,1)$, the spaces $R (S_r-\lambda I)$ and $R (S_{\ell}-\lambda I)$ are closed. Give an explicit representation of these spaces.

I'm trying to prove $R (S_{\ell}-\lambda I)$ is closed in (7). In my below attempt, I failed to prove that $|x|_2 < \infty$? Could you please elaborate on how to fix my proof?

---

I have proved in (6) that  $S_r^* = S_\ell$ and $S_{\ell}^* = S_r$. Then $(S_r-\lambda I)^*= S_{\ell}-\lambda I$ and $(S_\ell - \lambda I)^*= S_r-\lambda I$. By *Theorem 2.19* (in the same book), if $A$ is an unbounded linear operator which is densely defined and whose graph is closed, then $R(A)$ is closed iff $R(A^*)$ is closed. Let $\lambda \in(-1,1)$. It suffices to prove that $R(S_{\ell}-\lambda I)$ is closed.

The case $\lambda=0$ is clear. Let $\lambda \neq 0$. By *Theorem 2.19* again, it suffices to prove $R(S_r-\lambda I) = N(S_{\ell}-\lambda I)^\perp$. By (4), $N(S_{\ell}-\lambda I) = \operatorname{span} \{(1, \lambda, \lambda^2, \ldots, \lambda^n, \ldots)\}$. It remains to verify
$$
R(S_r-\lambda I) = F:= \left \{y \in E : \sum_{n=0}^\infty h^n y_{n+1} = 0 \right \}.
$$

For $x \in E$,
$$
(S_r - \lambda I)x = (-\lambda x_1, x_1 -\lambda x_2, x_2 -\lambda x_3, \ldots, x_{n-1} -\lambda x_n, \ldots).
$$

Then
$$
R(S_r-\lambda I) = \{ (-\lambda x_1, x_1 -\lambda x_2, x_2 -\lambda x_3, \ldots, x_{n-1} -\lambda x_n, \ldots) : x\in E\}.
$$

It's easy to see that $R(S_r-\lambda I) \subset F$. Let $y \in F$. Because $\lambda \neq 0$, we can pick $x_1 \in \mathbb R$ such that $y_1 = -\lambda x_1$. Then there is a unique $x_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that $y_2 = x_1 -\lambda x_2$. Recursively, for each $n \ge 1$ there is a unique $x_{n+1} \in \mathbb R$ such that $y_{n+1} = x_n -\lambda x_{n+1}$. Let $x := (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$. If we can verify that $|x|_2 < \infty$, then clearly, $(S_r-\lambda I) x=y$ and thus $y\in R(S_r-\lambda I)$. We have $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n-y_{n+1}}{\lambda}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Hint: Write $(\lambda I - S_r)x=y$ as $S_rx = \lambda x -y$, take norms, deduce that $\|x\| \le c \| (\lambda I - S_r)x\|$, which gives closedness by Thm 2.20 (I own a version of Brezis with solutions) It seems to be much harder to directly prove the closedness.

Comment: @daw Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can award you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $(\lambda I - S_r)x=y$ as $S_rx = \lambda x-y$, we get by taking norms
$$
\|S_rx\| = \|x\| \le |\lambda| \cdot \|x\| + \|y\|,
$$
so that
$$
\|x\| \le \frac 1{1-|\lambda|}\|y\| = \frac 1{1-|\lambda|}\| (\lambda I - S_r)x\|.$$
This implies that $\lambda I - S_r$ has closed range.