# Brezis' exercise 6.20.4: determine $T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Given $u \in E$, set
> $$
> T u(x) = \int_0^x u(t) \, d t .
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $T \in \mathcal{K}(E)$.
> 2. Determine $E V(T)$ and $\sigma(T)$.
> 3. Give an explicit formula for $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ when $\lambda \in \rho(T)$.
> 4. Determine $T^*$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (4). Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

Let $q \in (1, \infty]$ be the Hölder conjugate of $p$, i.e., $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$. Then $E^*=L^q(0, 1)$. For $u \in E$ and $v \in E^*$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle Tu, v \rangle_{E, E^*} &= \int_0^1 Tu(x) v(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^x u(t) \, d t \, v(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{[0, x]} (t) u(t) \, d t \, v(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1_{[t, 1]} (x) u(t) \, d t \, v(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \left ( \int_0^1 1_{[t, 1]} (x) v(x) \, dx \right ) u(t) \, d t \\
&= \int_0^1 \left ( \int_t^1 v(x) \, dx \right ) u(t) \, d t.
\end{align*}
$$

Then
$$
T^* v(t) = \int_t^1 v(x) \, dx.
$$

Comment: This is correct.