# Brezis' exercise 6.22.3: construct an example in $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $Q(E V(T)) \neq E V(Q(T))$ and $Q(\sigma(T)) \neq \sigma(Q(T))$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a real Banach space, and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. Given a polynomial $Q(t)=\sum_{k=0}^p a_k t^k$ with $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$, let $Q(T)=\sum_{k=0}^p a_k T^k$.
>
> 1. Prove that $Q(E V(T)) \subset E V(Q(T))$.
> 2. Prove that $Q(\sigma(T)) \subset \sigma(Q(T))$.
> 3. Construct an example in $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the above inclusions are strict.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (1, 2). Could you please have a check on it and give an example for (3)?

---

We have $Q(t) - Q(s)=(t-s) P(t, s) = P(t, s) (t-s)$ where $P(t, s)$ is a polynomial in two indeterminates.

1.

Let $\lambda \in Q(E V(T))$, i.e., there is $\mu \in EV(T)$ such that $\lambda = Q(\mu)$. We have $T - \mu I$ is not injective. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
Q(T) - \lambda I &= Q(T) - Q(\mu) I \\
&= Q(T) - Q(\mu I) \\
&= P(T, \mu I)(T-\mu I).
\end{align*}
$$

Because $T-\mu I$ is not injective, $Q(T) - \lambda I$ is not injective. Hence $\lambda \in EV(Q(T))$.

2.

Let $\lambda \in Q(\sigma(T))$, i.e., there is $\mu \in \sigma(T)$ such that $\lambda = Q(\mu)$. We have $T - \mu I$ is not bijective. We have
$$
\begin{align*}
Q(T) - \lambda I &= Q(T) - Q(\mu) I \\
&= Q(T) - Q(\mu I) \\
&\overset{(*)}{=} P(T, \mu I)(T-\mu I) \\
&\overset{(**)}{=} (T-\mu I) P(T, \mu I).
\end{align*}
$$

It follows from $(*)$ and $(**)$ that $Q(T) - \lambda I$ is not bijective. Hence $\lambda \in \sigma(Q(T))$.

Comment: For (3), try looking among those operators that have no (real) eigenvalues, with e.g. $Q(x) = x^2$.