# Brezis' exercise 6.23.7: prove that $\|T^n\| \le \frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $E$ be a real Banach space. Let $\mathcal L(E)$ be the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ and $\mathcal K(E)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $\| \cdot\|$ be the operator norm on $\mathcal L(E)$. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. For $T \in \mathcal L(E)$,

- we denote by $N(T)$ its kernel and by $R(T)$ its range.
- we denote by $\rho(T)$ its [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425), by $\sigma(T)$ its spectrum, and by $EV(T)$ its set of eigenvalues. Then $EV(T) \subset \sigma(T) = \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
- for $\lambda \in EV(T)$, the set $N(T-\lambda I)$ is called the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a real Banach space and $T \in \mathcal L (E)$. Let
> $$
> a_n := \log \|T^n\|
> \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
> $$
>
> 1. Check that $a_{n+m} \le a_n + a_m$ for all $m, n \ge 1$.
> 2. Deduce that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ exists and coincides with $\inf_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n}$.
> 3. Conclude that $r(T) := \lim_n \|T^n\|^{1/n}$ exists and that $r(T) \le \|T\|$. Construct an example in $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $r(T)=0$ and $\|T\|=1$.
>    The number $r(T)$ is called *spectral radius* of $T$.
> 4. Prove that $\sigma(T) \subset [-r(T), r(T)]$. Deduce that if $\sigma(T) \neq \emptyset$, then
>    $$
>    \max_{\lambda \in \sigma (T)} |\lambda| \le r(T).
>    $$
> 5. Construct an example in $E=\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$, while $r(T)=1$.
>
> In what follows we take $E=L^p(0,1)$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Consider the operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ defined by
> $$
> T u(t)=\int_0^t u(s) \, d s .
> $$
>
> 6. Prove by induction that for $n \geq 2$,
>    $$
>    \left(T^n u\right)(t) = \frac{1}{(n-1) !} \int_0^t(t-s)^{n-1} u(s) \, d s.
>    $$
> 7. Deduce that $\|T^n\| \le \frac{1}{n!}$.
> 8. Prove that the spectral radius of $T$ is $0$.
> 9. Show that $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (7) and (8). Could you please have a check on it?

---

We extend $u \in L^p (0, 1)$ on the whole $\mathbb R$ by defining $u (s)=0$ for $s \in \mathbb R \setminus (0, 1)$. For $n \ge 1$, we define
$$
K_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, s \mapsto 1_{[0, 1]} (s) s^{n-1}.
$$

Then $K_n \in L^1(0, 1)$ with $\|K_n\|_{L^1} = \frac{1}{n}$.

7.

By (6),
$$
\begin{align*}
(T^n u) (t) &= \frac{1}{(n-1) !} \int_{\mathbb R} 1_{[0, 1]} (t-s)(t-s)^{n-1} u(s) \, d s \\
&=  \frac{1}{(n-1) !} (K_n * u) (t).
\end{align*}
$$

Then $T^n u= \frac{K_n * u}{(n-1) !}$. By Young's convolution inequality,
$$
\|T^n u\|_{L^p} \le \frac{\|K_n\|_{L^1} \|u\|_{L^p}}{(n-1)!} = \frac{\|u\|_{L^p}}{n!}.
$$

Then $\|T^n\| \le \frac{1}{n!}$.

8.

By (3) and (7),
$$
\begin{align*}
r(T) = \lim_n \|T^n\|^{1/n} \le \lim_n \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}.
\end{align*}
$$

By [Stirling's formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stirling%27s_approximation#introduction),
$$
\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12 n+1}}<n !<\sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12 n}}.
$$

Then $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n <n!$ and thus $\frac{n}{e} < \sqrt[n]{n!}$. Then
$$
r(T) \le \lim_n \frac{2}{n} =0.
$$

Comment: The Stirling formula is an overkill. You can use: If $u_{n+1}/u_n\to a$ then $\sqrt[n]{u_n}\to a.$ Apply this to $u_n=1/n!.$ Alternatively you can use $(2n+1)!>(2n)!\ge (n+1)\cdot \ldots\cdot 2n\ge n^n.$